# Does sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT guarantee bit size?

Tags: c++, size, byte, bit, sizeof

There doesn't appear to be any library function for calculating the size of a type in bits.

Am I right to assume that this can be done in the following way?

```
#include <climits>

template <typename T>
size_t Size_In_Bits(){
    return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;
}
```

Will this always give back the amount of bits that can be targeted on a type?

Comment: What is a "bit that can be targeted on a type"?

Comment: @chux I've changed the C tag to C++.  Although, I'd like to know if there is any differences between languages.  The above implementation could instead be a C macro with limits.h

Comment: Confident there is no size difference between C/C++.

Comment: @immibis Yeah, I suppose that's misleading.  "The amount of bits that are physically stored in memory and could be changed via bit manipulations."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is guaranteed to give you *size* (storage) in bits, but not the *width* (number of value bits). The latter could be less if the type has padding bits. For unsigned types there you can measure the number of value bits directly by converting -1 to the type (to get the max possible value in the type) and counting them. For signed types, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` can be used to get the max. Or, if you know the specific type already, you can use the `xxx_MAX` macros from `limits.h` or `stdint.h`.

Comment: Good answer about "converting (unsigned) -1 to the type and counting them" and "no way to measure the number of value bits in a signed type".

Comment: "if you know which type it is" - or you can use `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`

Comment: Oh, sorry, the question was tagged C++ not C. In that case my answer is somewhat wrong...

Comment: Made some changes; hopefully it's better now.

Comment: @R..
I thought underflow was undefined behaviour?  Or is it different when you initialize and unsigned with negative 1?

Comment: @TrevorHickey: No underflow occurs. Integer conversions into unsigned types are well-defined and take place as reduction modulo TYPE_MAX+1.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT` returns the numbers of bits the type takes up in memory.

Yet the size of bits may be more than the bits the integer can be mathematically used - (consider padding bits).

---

Detail: integers have value bits, sign bit (signed integers) and possible padding bits.  All these bits contribute to the storage size.

`unsigned char` will never have padding bits.

Comment: Calling this "padding" is extremely misleading. Padding means something else in C and C++.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet The C Spec §6.2.6.2 2 calls the extra bits "padding bits".  "Padding" used here is not extremely misleading in C and C++ as it is used in 2 contexts: bits as mentioned here and padding bytes of structures.  Answer re-worked to called them _padding bits_ to help distinguish from _padding bytes_.  IAC, it is still a form of _padding_ per the language specification.

Comment: Maybe the C spec does, but the C++ spec does not (modulo a single, orphaned mention in non-normative text under §29.6.5 relating to `memcpy` behaviour). "Padding bits" however is still sufficiently disambiguating so thanks for adding the second word.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Note that at the time of this answer, post was tagged [C]and not [C++].  OP was ambivalent about C/C++ yet was using C++ `template` and later changed tag from C to C++.

Comment: "unsigned char will never have padding bits." -- untrue.

There exists at least one architecture, the Analog Devices SHARC, that has two different-sized memory busses: 32 bit (data) and 48 bits (code).
Depending on the segment in which the unsigned char is allocated, it has thus 32 or 48 bits -- not 8.
Because the processor's main registers all have 32 bits, when accessing unsigned char arrays in the code memory segment, there are 16 unusable padding bits per unsigned char -- when seen e.g. in a dense memory map.

We wrote a class for string constants to overcome the wasted memory.

Comment: @UnePierre True that `CHAR_BIT` may be larger than 8, yet "unsigned char will never have padding bits."  is true for compliant C compilers given C's spec: "For unsigned integer types other than `unsigned char`, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits". C17dr § 6.2.6.2 1.  Perhaps post your assertion and sample code as a SO question for additional informative feedback.